# How can i do about radio button value in angular-formly

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

how I can show and hide a field based on values of a radio button using ionic-formly

```
 {
            key: 'radioTest',
            type: 'radio',
            templateOptions: {
              options: [{
                value: 'true',
                text: 'YES',
                  }, {
                value: 'false',
                text: 'NO', 
              }]
            }
  },{
            "key": "email",
            "type": "stacked-input",
            "templateOptions": {
                "type":"email",
                "label": "Email",                       
                "placeholder": "Email"
                       },
              "expressionProperties":{
            "hide":function($viewValue,$modelValue,scope){
            return $scope.formData.radioTest
                                                     }
            }
        }
```

i'm waiting for your help

Comment: I would suggest editing the title of the question. it is very unclear as to what you're asking if you just look at the title.

Answer (score 1):

Use hideExpression;

```
 function getFields() {
            return [
              {
                            className: 'optional-className',
                            type: 'radio',
                            key: 'radioKey',
                            templateOptions: {
                                label: 'This is a label;',
                                labelProp: 'This is labelProp',
                                valueProp: 'id',
                                theme: 'default',
                                options: [
                                    {
                                        value: 'Yes',
                                        id: true
                                    },
                                    {
                                        value: 'No',
                                        id: false
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                            className: 'optional',
                            type: 'input',
                            key: 'inputSomewhatKey',
                            templateOptions: {
                                label: 'This is my beautiful label',
                                required: true,
                                theme: 'default',
                                labelProp: 'value',
                                valueProp: 'id',
                                options: [
                                    { value: 'value two', id: '1' },
                                    { value: 'value one', id: '2' },
                                ]
                            },
                            hideExpression: '!model.radioKey'
                        }
              }
 }
```